# Use Simpson's rule to estimate the error of integral $\int_1^5 \ln(x) \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, simpsons-rule

In my homework I'm requested to estimate the error of the definite integral:

1. $$\int_1^5 \ln(x) \mathrm dx$$

I am also given the formula:

2. $$|E_n|<= \frac {(K(b-a)^5)}{180N^4}$$

Where K is an upper bound for the fourth derivative ($|f^4(x)|$).
Given that 
$$|f^4(\ln (x))| = -\frac {6}{x^4}$$

I have to assume that 
$$|f^4(\ln (x))| = -\frac {6}{x^4} = -\frac {6}{5^4} = 0.0096$$

If I plug this value into the formula (2) I get [$2.133*10^{-4}$] which I am not sure about.

Any further explanation will be appreciated. I use Thomas Calculus and can't find much more.

Thanks

Comment: The upper bound for you're fourth derivative over this interval should be $6$, right? ($6/1^4$)

Comment: is that because of the lower limit in the range or is because of delta(x)?

Comment: Neither.  This is simply the max of the second derivative.  The reason for using the max derivative is that you want to be sure that, given a function, interval, and step size, your error is below a bound.

Comment: Not sure I grasp the second derivative, but I take that the maximum value for $|6/x^4|$ for a range from 1 to 5 can only be when $x=1$. Therefore that's my upper bound.

Comment: However, that still does not seem to get me the expected error approximation that I was looking for. Wolfram tells me that should be something like 0.044~ but if use $K=6$ I get nowhere near that....:-(

Comment: By the way, write **\ln** to generate $\ln$, **\mathrm dx** to generate $\mathrm dx$ and **\frac{x}{y}** to generate $\dfrac{x}{y}$

Comment: Sorry, I meant the fourth derivative.  What value of $N$ are you using?

Comment: I’m using $N=4$ thanks